# FFT of length 1536

Tags: signal-processing

Does anyone knows can i find a FFT of 1536 length input. Its a specification given in 3gpp Lte and we need a transform of 1536 input size which is neither a power of any number i would say. I just need a theoretical idea.

Comment: It divides into 3 512's, which is a power of 2. This should help http://www.altera.com/literature/an/an480.pdf

Comment: Duplicate on DSP.SE: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/8652/fft-of-input-length-1536

Answer (score 1):

[FFTW](http://www.fftw.org) provides an implementation on an arbitrary-N FFT,  and a quick search turned up [an implementation](http://www.corix.dk/Mix-FFT/mix-fft.html) from  Jens Jørgen Nielsen.

Failing that,  an academic literature search might be in order.  Searching for *Cooley Tukey* in a citations index is a safe bet.

Comment: FFTW is very efficient when the FFT size is a product of powers of small primes (2, 3, 5, 7), so 1536 = 2^9*3 should work well.

Comment: FTTW is ok , but I can't use it due to some company licensing problems.So, any other solutions.

Comment: @DegenerationAxe  - Agreed.  I had precisely the same issue with it on previous projects.

Answer (score 1):

A combination of 1 radix-3 and 9 radix-2 decimation-in-time FFT stages should work for an FFT of length of 1536.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for PRACH. The easiest way will be implement an upsampling filter of L/M ratio to go to the nearest FFT of size 2048.
Another way can directly take implement fft of 1536 also but that doesn't be an optimal solution as 2048 point fft will be much easier to take.

Comment: tell me what is another way to implement user2307595?